# нужная форма JButton

Tags: java

мне нужно что бы при нажатии на  кнопку JButton открывалась нужая JFrame
например у меня есть окно с кнопкой я нажимаю на кнопку и открыается нужная мне JFrame

Answer (score 0):

Создавайте экземпляр класса нужного JFrame при нажатии на кнопку.
Пример конструктора наследника JFrame:

```
public Window(String title, int windowXPos, int windowYPos, int windowWidth, int windowHeight){
    this.windowWidth = windowWidth;
    this.windowHeight = windowHeight;
    setFocusable(true); 
    setBounds(windowXPos, windowYPos, windowWidth, windowHeight);
    setTitle(title); 
    setVisible(true); 
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Comment: сделал уже, какой код нужно писать чтобы открывало

Comment: Вы не умеете создавать наследника JFrame? Если в конструкторе вашего наследника все в порядке, то оно должно открыться

Comment: нет не умею(((((

Comment: Обновил ответ .

Comment: Переведите пожалуйста скриншот в текст.

Comment: мне не надо создавать новую, мне надо что бы открылась моя

Comment: Подождите, вы же сказали, что не умеете создавать наследника JFrame. Для того, чтобы открыть свою, вам достаточно создать новый экземпляр наследника JFrame. Если не получится, приведите код вашего наследника JFrame.

Comment: vk.com/techis228 напиши мне я тебе все расскажу

Comment: Я помогаю по своему желанию. Вы же не вызываете его, поэтому справляйтесь сами.